# Bundle Install - Rails on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, unicorn

I have a problem with bundle install on production server. I have a fresh Droplet at DigitalOcean running Rails and Ubuntu 14.02. If I run as root:

```
bundle install
```

I get the following message and my application breaks, start getting "Bad Gateway" errors from Nginx:

```
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
```

If I run bundle install as the rails user:

```
su rails
bundle install
```

then I get this error:

```
sh: 1: bundle: not found
```

What am I missing? I've scoured the internet and tried every solution I can find and can't get it working quite right.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: You don't have the `budler` gem in your path. You may want to look into using something like `rvm` or `rbenv` to manage ruby for you.

Comment: When I try to install rvm as the user it says, "Could not download 'https://bitbucket.org/mpapis/rvm/get/1.26.4.tar.gz'.
  curl returned status '23'."

Comment: cURL status 23 means that it couldn't write to your local file system, are you sure you're downloading it to the right directory?

Comment: I can run rvm as root but not as user, otherwise I get the curl status 23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the Bundler gem is installed for root user but not the rails user.

1. If you are not using a ruby version manager such as rbenv or rvm, do: `gem install bundler`.
2. If you have a ruby version manager, your rails user doesn't have
   access to it because you installed it for 1 user only. In this case, your problem is more than not being able to run bundler. You might not have rails or even ruby installed at all for that user.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today，when i deploy my web app on vps.

the ruby version manages is RVM,

i try to install new ruby version 2.2.2,but the problem had appear

then try install new bundler version, the machine bundler is latest 1.12.3

```
gem uninstall bundler -v 1.12.3
gem install bundler -v 1.11.0
```

the issue has to solve